# Object has no attribute _set', Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have these models:

```
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_number_of_categorys_items(self):
        return self.post_set.count()


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategory, related_name='blog_category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And when I try to call method `get_number_of_categorys_items` it cause error:

> AttributeError: 'BlogCategory' object has no attribute 'post_set'

This method should return number of posts with this category.

What can I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you've specified the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), Django would not automatically create the related name as `post_set` for you. Either use:

```
def get_number_of_categorys_items(self):
    return self.blog_category.count()
```

Or, don't specify the `related_name`:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategory)
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful !

Comment: @Alecxe, thank you, very helpful! I spent many hours on a related issue, and the only problem was adding a related_name to the ForeignKey field.